# Are community licenses necessary?

Tags: community, integration, customer-community, architecture

I'm trying to understand the Salesforce's licensing model in widespread integration scenario: the client needs to expose some Salesforce functionalities to final customers eg. case submission, profile (account) editing, etc through a third party self-care site (not a community).

The client's architect is thinking about a data replication on heroku or some other PAAS solution. The company site will access data from heroku, not from Salesforce. In this case, does the client need to buy Customer Community Licenses even if the don't actually use Community functionalities and interface?

Piero

Comment: Nope. But you will have to architect it carefully and understand how you will handle data skew from the differences between the real time data and the cloned data. Not sure why you would need to clone the whole DB as you could simply use the API to interact with SF data from the third party website but then again I also do not know the scope of your project so.

Comment: Thank you very much Eric. 
As I wrote the decision to replicate the entire db has been taken by the client's architect.

Anyway I made this question because aur Salesforce Account Representative argues that getting customer data from salsforce and expose it on the company web site using a single integration user would violate Salesforce Master Service Agreement. He sustains that the client need to buy Salesforce Cloud Licenses. It's a very weird position and seems a way to sell more licenses.

Comment: Your rep was wrong(most likely). After all. That's why they made API's. The data is owned by you and as long as you have a separate API user you are violating anything. But IANAL